# Standard Practice for Accessing Back End Data which Logon to use

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, authentication

**Question:** What is the standard method for accessing back end data, which logon should you use?

**Examples:**

For example we have applications that require the user to login but then use an admin account to access the data from the backend.

But there are also applications that require the user to login and use those credentials to access the backend data.

**Reason:** We are in the process of creating an application that will require the user to login and would like to implement the more common method(standard practice) of accessing data.

If there are alternatives those are also welcome.

**Note:** This will be made in ASP.Net 3.5 or higher and may include Windows Applications(VB.Net) as well.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I dont want to have two sets of credentials. What I am asking is which credentials are normally used to access the Database. For example one one application may access 2 or more database's. Now would you use the same credentials they used to login to the application or would you use the admin account to access the data?

**Edit 2:** Maybe this should be a seperate question but if I ended up using integrated security to access the database would the user be able to simply connect to the database using his AD account? Either through an ODBC connection and MS Access or equiv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just create a login table and a table of roles for the user?  You can have a user be an Admin or a User just by setting their roles either in the Login table or in a separate table if a user can be more than one.  Having 2 sets of credentials seems a pain to me.

Comment: If you want to control data access from within sql server then you could use integrated security in your connection string.  You may have to do some impersonation to do this correctly.  Alternatively you can control a user's access to data in the system through the front end code then use a single restricted account in the connection string to access the data.  I usually prefer the second method as the first method will require each user to also be configured in the database security as well.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for. Do you know between those two methods which one is the standard practice? I also prefer the second method but the decision on which way to go will be made by the higher ups.

Comment: They are both a standard practice and fully supported by .NET.  In general I find using a restricted account is better (in many situations) than using integrated security because with integrated security you will probably have to handle dealing with user account permissions in both the DB as well as in your application (for items such as not showing admin screens to non-admins etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use a single restricted permission account to access the database. This would be used as part of an application level connection string.

If you are set on having individual accounts for each user to access the database then you will need to construct the connection string dynamically using the appropriate individual username and password. You will need to store these in a table somewhere. You may find that [SQL Server connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) becomes less effective with many different connection strings being used.

An alternative would be to use Windows authentication but this would generally require all users to be part of the same domain and you haven't indicated whether this would be possible in your case.

Comment: Hey @Simon, all users would be part of the same domain. We are trying to make a case to use Windows Authentication because our auditors are against it at the moment. I am going to look into connection pooling as you suggested.

Comment: a quick question so i understand this correctly. When using integrated security, and 2 different users are accessing the northwind database, would that use one connection pool or two?

Comment: My understanding is that as the connection strings are identical for each user SQL Server will be able to optimise connection pooling. When the connection strings differ (with different username and/or password) SQL Server is unable to reuse existing connection pools so effectively. Whether this will make a real-world difference to your application is another matter, there would be a performance hit but you might not notice it due to other bottlenecks.